# Trying to install Fusion Middleware in Solaris 11.4

Tags: java, installation, virtual-machine, solaris, oracle-fusion-middleware

I'm trying to install Fusion Middleware to a Solaris 11.4 virtual machine, but I get the error:

```
This installer must be executed using a java development kit (JDK)
but /usr/jdk/instances/jdk.1.8.0/jre is not a valid jdk java home
```

I don't know why is trying to use the jre directory, when I run "which java" to see what path the command is set to, I get "usr/bin/java", but that path is a shortcut so it's more like "usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java".

I haven't installed anything yet,I was about to start with Middleware, but if I'm already using a java executable from a directory called JDK then I'm not sure what's causing this error with JRE.

Comment: Is there a Java directory in the PATH?

Comment: Yes, I added "usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" as $JAVA_HOME with: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java

Comment: OK, so I downloaded the SDK from the internet and instead of calling the java command I called the executable, I don't want to include it into PATH just yet tho, I'll first figure out where I'll put it, but for now I get to install Middleware at least.